# SQL: last 7 Days Calculations based on date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Below Tables consists of count of users on particular day.Looking to populate Total_Users signup column

Logic:Contains user count b/w Signupdate-14 & Signupdate-7

For Example: 15/01/2020 , contains users count between 1/1/2020 AND 1/7/2020

```
Signupdate|  |Users| Total_Users(b/w D-14 & D-7)
1/1/2020  |  |20.  | 60 
2/1/2020  |  |30.  | 80 
3/1/2020  |  |10.  | 90
---       |  |--   | --
---       |  |--   | --
15/1/2020 |  |30.  | 120
16/1/2020 |  |10.  | 40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Signupdate
           , Users
           ,SUM(CASE 
                WHEN Signupdate BETWEEN to_date(Signupdate,'DDMMYYYY')-14 and to_date(Signupdate,'DDMMYYYY')-7
                THEN Users END) AS 'Total_Users'
FROM
```

This is assuming that the users column is of numeric type

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a row for each date, you would use window functions with a windowing clause.  I'm not sure if Redshift supports window frames with intervals, but this is the basic logic:

```
select t.*,
       sum(users) over (order by signupdate
                        range between interval '-14' day and interval '-7 day'
                       ) as total_users
from t;
```

If not, you can turn the date into a number and use that:

```
select t.*,
       sum(users) over (order by signupdate
                        rows between 14 preceding and 7 preceding
                       ) as total_users
from (select t.*,
             datediff(day, signupdate, date '2000-01-01') as diff
      from t
     ) t
```

I am guessing you want a complete week.  However, this is 8 days.